# Can't install "Skype for Business" with "Office Click-to-run" installer

Tags: skype, office365

My employer has Office 365, and I'm trying to install "Skype for Business" on my home computer (which already has office). When I try to download and install the software, I get the error message:

```
We found a problem!

We're sorry, Office Click-to-Run installer encoutered a problem
because you have these Windows Installer based Office programs 
installed on your computer:

 Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013
```

Apparently the click-to-run installer doesn't play nice with my local office install. Is there a workaround for this? (e.g., a "Windows Installer" edition of skype for business?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is pretty clear if you work in IT - but not very clear if you don't deal with installing packages all day.  Microsoft has two different versions of office.

From the O365 Portal you get what is called "click to run" - which installs via a streaming service.  It basically streams the application down to you - and you can actually start using it before it's installed completely.

As you uncovered another versions is what is called MSI based - this is the traditional install method for windows applications. Here - you have to download the entire package and then install it before you can use office.

Technically - there are ways to get these both on your system, but it's not a good idea which is why Microsoft blocks you. When you have both on your system some things stop working - particularly with the integration with online products or web based products.  For example - trying to open or save directly to O365 from an application wouldn't work and you would see error messages.

It's a shame MS can't provide more clarification - the message could actual tell you what you have installed or how to correct the issue.

Comment: So what's the fix to get around this when on Windows 7? I have this problem too and can't access the Windows 10 store as mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not aware of a "full client" MSI version out there.   The basic version is available here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49440

Comment: Thank you. I ended up installing Lync 2013 instead which works fine for my organization.

Answer (score 2):

D'oh. Apparently you can just install it via the Windows store.

Comment: While this might have been true when u wrote this, it unfortunately is no longer

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still searching for an answer on this, I found Microsoft have provided installers that worked for me in this situation (Windows 10, O365 version of Office 2016, click to run install error):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/wiki/msoffice_other-mso_other/skype-for-business-is-removed-when-you-upgrade-to/989e2795-7a43-4b7b-ab3e-8eff5788e8d1